# setting default value for select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

How can we set the default value for the select2 dropdown when initializing it with something like:

```
$('.className').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    data: dataArray
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine - you just need to add a blank `<option></option>` tag in your `select` element.

For example:

```
<select id="listOfNames">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Shyam">Shyam</option>
  <option value="James">James</option>
  <option value="Helen">Helen</option>
  <option value="Dave">Dave</option>
</select>
```

You can apply the placeholder as an option to select2 (as you have in your example) or as a the `data-placeholder` attribute of the `select` element.

Also, you can provide select2 with the `allowClear : true` property which allows users to remove an item once they have selected it (returning to the placeholder).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djuuuh80/3/

Note: Select boxes with the **multiple** attribute set automatically use the placeholder if provided without the need for the blank `<option>` tag.

Comment: I fixed this issue yday myself. But initially I wanted to do it this way by using the select2's apis. Later I made a select tag with details and then based on what I wanted to keep default I made the selected attribute